# How does a Webform able to differentiate among radio buttons, check boxes and Lists

Tags: 7, webforms

I am using **webform module** to build forms. Initially i created a simple form with few components like **text-field**, **text-area**, **radios**, **check boxes** , **Drop down list** and submitted it.

When i checked the database,  I found that the module is storing type "**select**" for the components radio, check boxes and lists in table name "**webform_component**". I want to know how can we **differentiate** them.

Please check the screenshot, 
[image]

While creating the form i choose the following parameters

**Gender** ----> **Radio**

**Range**  ----> **List**

**Hobbies**----> **Checkbox**

But in the table it was shown as "**select**" for all the fields

Can anyone suggest the way to find out ?

Answer (score 0):

the `webform_component` table also has an `extra` column you've cropped out.

It's SQL column help description is:

> Additional information unique to the display or processing of this
>   component.

A `select` can simply be rendered many ways -- I believe the display settings for the "selectable options" used in rendering a radio, list or checkbox are in that column.

Comment: Sorry i dint mentioned in my post, I have examined extras column, the only differentiation i observed is for a      radio it stores b:0 and b:o                                 for checkbox b:1 and b:0                                                   for list b:0 and b:1, But  i am expecting something which is easier to be differed. Hope you understand my point Thanks for your valuable reply

Comment: hehe ... why would you "expect" something easy !? a Webform is not a core drupal form built with the core  FAPI. The webform maintainers long ago built their own form storage, and description "api". This is the result of that. Please read http://drupal.org/node/325766 and you will see that radio,list and checkbox in webform components all come from `select` in their API. It does look like that DB column and data derives how it is shown. You may have a better time differenietating them in a hook_form_alter after webform has done some initial processing to load them up ...